# Image created via Javascript not displayed

Tags: javascript, image, firefox-addon, createelement

I'm writing a extension for Firefox that adds images to the current web page. Although it shouldn't be a problem, the following code snippet doesn't work. I got a 50px/50px rectangle, i.e., the border of the image, but the image itself is not displayed.

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.style.border = "1px solid #000";
img.style.width = "50px";
img.style.height = "50px";
img.setAttribute("src", "chrome://myExtension/content/images/add-icon.png");
```

It also doesn't work with images from a external results. Adding div-environments seem to work. img.src="..." doesn't change anything.

I try to add the image to a div. After adding div.length has increased by 1. So somehow everything is working, except the image is not displayed. Any hints?

Thanks and best regards,

Christian

Comment: Try if image resource is available? Open chrome://myExtension/content/images/add-icon.png and see if you can see this image in FF browser

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Putting the resource in the address bar works. As I mentioned, also external images with a http://... as source are not displayed via Javascript

Comment: try img.src = "chrome://myExtension/content/images/add-icon.png";

Comment: I tried this already (see the remark in my initial comment). I've tried various examples I found on the web, but not one worked. That actually something is added to the parent node I just noticed when I added style information and the parentNode.children.length increases by 1. That's my trouble, everything seems fine, except that the image is not displayed. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You've shown us the `document.createElement` call, can you also show us how the element is added to the document after that?

Comment: Since I cannot answer myself, here in short: var body = content.document.getElementsByTagName("BODY").item(0); var img = document.createElement("img"); img.src = "chrome://myExtension/content/images/add-icon.png"; var divBox = document.createElement("div"); divBox.appendChild(img); body.appendChild(divBox);

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but you are mixing "content.document" and "document" here. What happens if you use "content.document" consistently?

Comment: (Oh, and you should have been able to edit your answer to put the new code in, I think.)

Comment: Matthew, you were right! With "content.document" for all elements it works just fine. Strange that it worked to some degree. Well, many thanks a lot for your help. Also thanks to all others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var body = content.document.getElementsByTagName("BODY").item(0);
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "chrome://myExtension/content/images/add-icon.png";
var divBox = document.createElement("div");
divBox.appendChild(img);
body.appendChild(divBox);
```

As discussed in comments, use "content.document" consistently, instead of mixing "content.document" and "document".

Answer (score 1):

Have you set contentaccessible?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome_registration#contentaccessible

It's required in order to make chrome images etc. available from non-chrome content.

Comment: Yes, I did. For example, it works when I add the div and img "manually" by adding the corresponding HTML string directly to the content (content.document.body.innerHTML). But this is not a nice solution. Additionally, contentaccessible is only relevant for accessing images of my extension, right? But it also does not work for external images (img.src="http://...")